# GWT 2.0 RC1 & GXT 2.0.1

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I'm wondering if already someone tried to use this combination ( GWT 2.0 RC1 with GXT 2.0.1 or any other version) and if so, then how it actually works ? any pitfalls ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

GWT 2.0 MS2 and GXT 2.0.1 has worked fine for me at least so far. But I will probably get rid of the whole GXT stuff soon. It's such a hog..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like GXT 2.1.1 has been released, and it's got support for GWT 2.0 and 1.7.